# Is there any way to add .net 4.5.1 support to Teamcity 7.1?

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity-7.1

I want to build my .net application in teamcity using new version of the framework. What I did is install new framework (using this installer: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40779) on the build agent machine. And after this I'm still do not see MSBuild of needen version on the build step configuration (only .net 4.5, 4.0 and so on). All that I found in official documentaion is that support of the  Microsoft Build Tools 2013 availible since teamcity 8.1 (http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/MSBuild). Is that means that I can't build project using new framework? Or what can I do to make things work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no new version of MSBuild, you still use 4.5